# Pizzle - Will you ever show up, Rick?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, calculation-puzzle

*NB: Pizzle = Puzzle + Riddle*

### Chapter 1: Let's start *(solved in comments)*

> You can see me, but you can not catch me
>
> I'm lightweight, but I could lift you up easily

### Chapter 2: The First Piece *(solved in comments)*

> I'm that one, which will never have a three
>
> To keep going, don't forget to grab the ID

### Chapter 3: The Recipe

> To find the key:
>
> 1. Add the sum of the digits *(solved in comments)*
> 2. Add the two first characters of your defenders
> 3. Add the two last characters of the shrunken big apple
> 4. Add the number shared by Haley and Bruce
> 5. Add the symbol of closure (twice)

### Chapter 4: The End

> What you are looking for is too long, you gotta shorten it
>
> Reverse it, and you will finally find Ricky!

**Hint :**

> Chapter 1 has been resolved in the comments

**Hint 2:**

> Chapter 1 & 2 are strongly related, to accomplish Chapter 2, you will need to find an URL.

**Hint 3:**

> You will need to use Chapter 3 to find an URL for Chapter 4...when you "reverse" this url, you will be able to find Rick :)

**Hint 4:**

> 3.2 refers to a group of people/job that defend you on a daily basis (when you need them at least)
> 3.4 refers to the name of a movie
> 3.5 is one symbol you use everyday on your computer

**Hint 5:**

> Once you have the 'ID' from Chapter 3, try it with one of the main URL shorteners and you will find the answer

Comment: Can we get a hint for 2?

Comment: @PerpetualJ sure

Comment: Can we change "pizzle" to like "rizzle" or something? B/c pizzle means a male bovine's reproductive organ (trying to keep this professional here). Don't ask how I know. Scrabble does weird stuff to you.

Comment: And apparently rizzle is a word too some sort of fidget toy, and also means to relax after a heavy meal? I officially quit English.

Comment: Yeah this is def not related to any bovin organ lmao

Comment: Rot13 Fgrnz jvyy arire unir unys yvsr 3  as part of chapter 2 not sure about ID though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chapter 1:

> Steam *(Solved by @OfFPiR)*

Chapter 2:

> 220 - Steam Id of Half-life 2 *(Solved by @Ranma344)*

Chapter 3:

> 1) **4** = 2+2+0
>
> 2) **po** from police
>
> 3) **yc** from NYC > shrunken New York City
>
> 4) **6** from Sixth Sense?
>
> 5) **xx** twice the (x) close button

Chapter 4:

> Shortening it using tinyurl, we get:
> tinyurl.com/4poyc6xx

Conclusion:

> Which leads us to a classic video of **Rick** Astley's Never Gonna Give You Up
> I guess this is where Rick is?

Comment: well played ! That was a long wait but worthwhile rick roll

Comment: Yes. Well played indeed. All this time I was thinking you were referencing Rick from Rick and Morty. When I finally arrived at the place where Rick is, I felt betrayed.

Answer (score 2):

### ***Partial Answer***

This is well crafted and has proven to be difficult; none the less I am still trying to solve it!

**Chapter 1**:

> Per @OfFPiR this is **steam**.
>  
>  
>  ***You can see me, but you can not catch me.***
>  
>  Steam is visible to the naked eye, but is a gas so you can't catch it with your bare hands.
>  
>  
>  ***I'm lightweight, but I could lift you up easily.***
>  
>  This refers to old fashioned hot air balloons and blimps.

**Chapter 3**:

> ***Add the sum of the digits***: **Unknown**.
>  
>  
>  
>  ***Add the two first characters of your defenders***: **Unknown**.
>  
>  
>  
>  
>  
>  ***Add the two last characters of the big apple***: **NY**
>  
>  This is most likely New York.
>  
>  
>  
>  ***Add the number shared by Haley and Bruce***: **Unknown**.
>  
>  
>  
>  
>  
>  ***Add the symbol of closure***: **Unknown**.

Comment: You can't technically see [your answer] since [first guess] itself is invisible and [your other guess] is simply a byproduct of moving [first guess] so [your other guess] is invisible too.

Comment: Though I can't really think of anything else

Comment: Thus the byproduct makes it “visible”.

Comment: I was thinking more in the line of rot13(Fgrnz naq fgrnz ratvarf)

Comment: You are close ! @OfFPiR you found it :)

Comment: @PerpetualJ, New york is correct but the "2 last characters" are not RK :D I actually updated the text so it's more accurate and easier to guess

Answer (score 2):

Partial Thoughts:

Chapter 2:

> Being that we know we are looking at steam, and referring to Half Life, I did some digging to find the URL for the steam database for Half Life and Half Life 2, they are https://steamdb.info/app/70/ and https://steamdb.info/app/220/ From that we can extract that the games have ID's of 70 and 220

Chapter 3:

> Here we need to first add the digits of the ID's, which gives 3 possibilities of 7, 4, and 11. Still working this part out.

Comment: you found it ! :) - 2nd is correct, it'is the one "which will never have a three"

Answer (score 1):

So to summarize, we have:

Chapter 1:

> Steam, which apparently specifically refers to the Steam game engine.

Chapter 2:

> Half-life is the series of games that will not have an official third installment. The IDs of the games are 70 and 220. However, as OP suggested in a comment to @Ranma344 answer, it is specifically Half-Life 2 that will never develop into a third installment.

Chapter 3.1:

> Since OP is referring only to HL2, the sum of the digits of the game's ID is 2+2+0=4

Chapter 3.2:

> Overall, the puzzle has been following a digital trend. It is possible that our defenders are anti-malware programs if this trend continues. Hint 4 suggests that the clue is about people though, so it might have to do with the IT industry. So maybe IT?

Chapter 3.3:

> New York has been confirmed to be correct, but OP has said that the last two characters are not RK. I suspect that this has to do with the 'shrunken' part of the clue but once I get to thinking about that all I picture is a rotten apple and for some reason get that stuck in my head. Maybe it's shrinking the word down to just 'new' so that we end up with EW? Unsure.

Chapter 3.4:

> I immediately thought of Halley's comet and the years that it has been/is expected to be sighted. This however is a different spelling and I don't know where Bruce fits in. Moreover, Hint 4 says that the name of a movie somehow fits in and I am unaware of any cinematic presentation involving Halley's comet. There are, however, movies that are named with just numbers.

Chapter 3.5:

> XX. When closing apps on computers, X is the symbol that we click on. I can't think of any more explicit symbol of closure that is consistent across multiple applications. (Again, sticking with the digital trend of the puzzle.)

Chapter 4:

> Probably shorten the URL with bit.ly, then I suspect that the answer will be pretty obvious

Comment: nice thinking, you got some good points

Answer (score 1):

Partial

Chapter 3.1

> Marked as solved, but still not sure if it's supposed to be 4 or 11

Chapter 3.2

> Even with the hint, I have no idea what you're going for here. Cops? Firefighter? Army? Military? What kind of defending?

Chapter 3.3

> Shrunken big apple: NYC. Last two: **YC**

Chapter 3.4

> The Sixth Sense - Actors Haley Joel Osment and Bruce Willis. Thus: **6**

Chapter 3.5

> As @kanoo pointed out, **XX**

Chapter 4

> I'm assuming the base url is still the steam url with the id (ex 220) replaced with what we get from chapter 3?
> Also, apparently the id portion for url shorteners is case sensitive, which makes this even more variable and difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 2:

> Steam from chapter 1 never released its 3rd game in a series called half life.
>  There is one item that has a half life with a 3. Hydrogen-3 or Tritium. I am not sure how to derive an ID from it though. I tried checking steam for games about Tritium and only got Workshop items.

Comment: You are on the right track, but you are going too far :P

Comment: Is it the first or the second one I should be looking at?

Comment: Look at @Ranma344 :)